# Optimized point on line finding algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, geometry

I'm looking for an optimized integer-based point-on-line algorithm, where you can define the line using begin and end coordinates, and the point to find based on either an x or y input.

I know how to do this using dy/dx division but I'm looking for an algorithm that eliminates all divisions.

This is what I'm currently doing:

```
int mult = ((px - v0.x)<<16) / (v1.x - v0.x);
vec2 result{px, v0.y + (lerpmult*(v1.y - v0.y))>>16};
```

The division in the first line is the problem I'm trying to eliminate.

Comment: If you're just looking for an algorithm, why is this tagged `c++` instead of `algorithm` ?

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, I'm editing it right now

Comment: Just take a look at the conditions in your current algorithm. Multiply by the divisors and you get the same functionality without division.

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for (the question is a little unclear), but the Bresenham Line Algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) may do what you need.  Give two integer endpoints, it computes the integer points between the two without any division operations.  There is a floating point component to measure the error, but no division.  It's also very fast.

Comment: @andand I've indeed looked at the Bresenham algorithm, and you can do it with integers only, but I haven't found a way to convert it to a point-on-line algorithm, the Bresenham line algorithm looks too dependant to work in steps

Comment: @MrSmith42 I edited my post to contain my current code

Answer (score 0):

One trick to solve this would be using the [scalar product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_product) to determine the cosine of the angle between two vectors:

```
def line_test(a, b, p):
    v_ap = tuple(m - n for n, m in zip(a, p))
    v_ab = tuple(m - n for n, m in zip(a, b))

    scp = sum(m * n for m, n in zip(v_ap, v_ab))

    return scp > 0 and scp * scp == sum(n * n for n in v_ap) * sum(n * n for n in v_ab) and all(m <= n for m, n in zip(v_ap, v_ab))
```

[image: two vectors]

The parameters of the above function are the end-points of the line (`a` and `b`) and the point `p` (`c` in the image), which we want to test.

Step by step the following happens in each line:

1. `v_ap = tuple(m - n for n, m in zip(a, p))`
   We calculate the vector from `a` to `p` (`v_ap`)
2. `v_ab = tuple(m - n for n, m in zip(a, b))`
   The vector from `a` to `b` (`v_ab`)
3. `scp = sum(m * n for m, n in zip(v_ap, v_ab))`
   In this line the scalar product of `v_ap` and `v_ab` is calculated. The result is `scp = cos(v_ab, v_ap) * euclidean_length(v_ab) * euclidean_length(v_ap)`, where the euclidean length of a vector is defined as `sqrt(sum(n * n for n in vector))` (the standard definition of the geometric length of a vector).
4. `return scp > 0 and scp * scp == sum(n * n for n in v_ap) * sum(n * n for n in v_ab) and all(m <= n for m, n in zip(v_ap, v_ab)`
   This line is pretty complex, so I'll break it down into a few parts:

`scp * scp == sum(n * n for n in v_ap) * sum(n * n for n in v_ab)`
Since division isn't allowed, we shouldn't use the square-root either, since it's calculation usually involves divisions. So instead of calculating the square-root, we take the square of both the euclidean length of both vectors and the scalar product, thus eliminating the square-root calculation:

```
scp = cos(v_ab, v_ap) * euclidean_length(v_ab) * euclidean_length(v_ap) =
    = cos(v_ab, v_ap) * sqrt(sum(n ^ 2 for n in v_ab)) * sqrt(sum(n ^ 2 for n in v_ap))

scp ^ 2 = cos(v_ab, v_ap) ^ 2 * sum(n ^ 2 for n in v_ab) * sum(n ^ 2 for n in v_ap)
```

The cosine of the angle between the two vectors should be 1, if they point in the same direction. So the square of the scalar product if the vectors share the same direction would be

```
euclidean_length(v_ap) ^ 2 * euclidean_length(v_ab) ^ 2
```

which we then compare to the actual scalar product `scp`.

This however leaves one problem: taking the square eliminates the sign, which we check separately with the comparison `scp > 0`. Since the euclidean length is always positive, only the sign of the cosine determines the value of `scp`. A negative value of `scp` means that the angle of between `v_ap` and `v_ab` is at least `pi / 4` and at most `pi * 3/4`. However the sign of `scp` get's lost when squaring, which means that we can only check whether the two vectors are parallel, not if they point into the same direction. This problem is solved by checking `scp > 0` in addition.

Last but not least we have to check whether the distance from `a` to `p` is shorter than the distance from `a` to `b`. This can be done by checking whether `v_ap` has a smaller length than `v_ab`. Since we already checked that the two vectors point into exactly the same direction, it is sufficient check whether all elements in `v_ap` are at most as large as the corresponding element in `v_ab`, which is done by

```
all(m <= n for m, n in zip(v_ap, v_ab))
```

Comment: Thanks, I have to go to my job now but when I get back I'll try it out

Comment: This looks like a really good read, thank you for all the effort

Comment: @Lolslayer don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)  this answer, if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: I won't, I can finally give it a try today

Comment: I'm so terribly sorry, even though this is extremely helpful (I'll probably use it one day), it's not what I'm looking for, what I was looking for was an algorithm where you define a line, and then give either a single x or y coordinate, and the algorithm should show you what y or x coordinate belongs to the coordinate input when it's placed on the line

Answer (score 0):

The answer what you are finding is as follows:

Lets say our line equation is `Ax + By + C = 0`. Then we just need
this three coefficients (`A`, `B` and `C`).

Say this line goes through point `P(P_x, P_y)` and `Q(Q_x, Q_y)`. Then
it is easy to calculate the above three coefficients.

```
A = P_y - Q_y,
B = Q_x - P_x,
C = - A P_x - B P_y
```

Once we have our line equation, we can easily calculate `x` or `y`
coordinate for given `y` or `x` respectfully.

Here is my `c++` template:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// point struct
struct pt {
    int x, y;
};

// line struct
struct line {
    int a, b, c;

    // create line object
    line() {}
    line (pt p, pt q) {
        a = p.y - q.y;
        b = q.x - p.x;
        c = - a * p.x - b * p.y;
    }

    // a > 0; is must be true otherwise runtime error will occure
    int getX(int y) {
        return (-b * y - c) / a;
    }

    // b > 0; is must be true otherwise runtime error will occure
    int getY(int x) {
        return (-a * x - c) / b;
    }
};

int main() {
    pt p, q;
    p.x = 1, p.y = 2;
    q.x = 3, q.y = 6;
    line m = line(p, q);
    cout << "for y = 4, x = " << m.getX(4) << endl;
    cout << "for x = 2, y = " << m.getY(2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
for y = 4, x = 2
for x = 2, y = 4
```

Ref: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/segments_intersection

Comment: Thanks for the input, while this is really well written and has some very nice code accompanied to it, there's a division included in the calculation, which I tried to avoid, specified in the post with this quote:
"I know how to do this using dy/dx division but I'm looking for an algorithm that eliminates all divisions."

Comment: Is that ok, if your calculated `x` or `y` not be an integer? If so, then may be I have solution.

Comment: Prefferably not but I'm still interested in what you have in mind